# Helping with Join of output from DF and LSBLK Linux commands via bash

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, sed, awk

I already asked this question, but without update. I think this information should be related to this `site`.
I need to merge two outputs in Linux. This:

```
lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | grep -v "fd0" | grep -v "loop" | grep -v "sr0" | grep -v "hdc" | grep -v "cdrom"
```

In a result I have:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 /
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd
```

And this:

```
df --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | awk '{print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}'
```

In a result, I have:

```
/ /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
/dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
/dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
/var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
```

So, I want to Join via these points `/`, `/var/lib/docker`, `/dockerhdd`, `/dockerssd`.
Important! I want to check this in another place, where we will have another mount points. Also I have to save structure of first output without sorting.

In a result I have to receive something like this:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
```

Some person from `stackoverflow` helped me via `AWK`, but his answer did not help me. Also I have changed his command in a little bit.

```
awk '/^dm-*/ || /^sd*/ || /^xvd*/ { print $0" "arr[$5] } /^Filesystem/ { mrk=1;next } mrk==1 { arr[$6]=$0 }' <<< $(df --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay};lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT)
```

But in a result, I have

```
sda   sda                   53687091200  fd0   fd0                          4096
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048  sda   sda                   53687091200
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 / sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000  dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 /
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424  sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker
sdc   sdc                  536870912000  dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424  sdc   sdc                  536870912000
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
```

I want to receive this:

```
sda   sda                   53687091200
sda1  └─sda1                53684994048
dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%
sdb   sdb                 2147483648000
sdb1  └─sdb1              2147482599424
dm-1    ├─hddVG-dockerLV   536866717696 /var/lib/docker /dev/mapper/hddVG-dockerLV 76046204 412729940 16%
dm-2    └─hddVG-hddLV     1610612736000 /dockerhdd /dev/mapper/hddVG-hddLV 83278236 1385191240 6%
sdc   sdc                  536870912000
sdc1  └─sdc1               536869863424
dm-0    └─ssdVG-ssdLV      536866717696 /dockerssd /dev/mapper/ssdVG-ssdLV 214133656 274642488 44%
```

Comment: I don't understand the resulting output `dm-3    └─dockerVG-rootLV   53682896896 / /dev/mapper/dockerVG-rootLV 8110496 40591632 17%`. Where comes the first '`/`' come from? From your description, I would expect a join where the last column of `lsblk`  and the first column of `df` are the keys, but that does not match with your example outputs.

Comment: yes, I don't understand, how to do this. Could You help me in this ?

Comment: But can you then edit your question to produce the correct example-outputs?

Comment: I told, that I don't need to sort columns. From my example, `/` means mount point. I have this mount point from two outputs. It is last column in first output and first column in second output. I want to merge via this output these columns. In place, where I don't have mount points, I just want to have space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be a simple shell script. You may produce bizar, incomprehensible one-liners, but an understandable shell script is better maintable.

```
#!/bin/bash

df -h --exclude={tmpfs,devtmpfs,squashfs,overlay} | sed -e /^Filesystem/d | awk '{print $6 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5}' > /tmp/dinges.$$

lsblk -n -b --output KNAME,NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT | egrep -v "fd0|loop|sr0|hdc|cdrom" | 
while read kname name size mountpoint ; do
    printf '%-5s' "$kname"
    printf '%-20s' "$name"
    printf '%15d' "$size"
    printf '%-10s' "$mountpoint"
    if [ "$mountpoint" != "" ] ; then
        grep "$mountpoint " /tmp/dinges.$$
    else
        echo
    fi
done
rm /tmp/dinges.$$
```

Now understand that this is a quick write. There are a lot of issues with this script (like spaces in the mountpoint names), but it should give you an idea what to do.

Comment: Your script does not work.
When I try to execute it I got unexpected end of file errors on lines 12 and 18.

Comment: I just submitted an edit to your answer.